# Get email account into textfield using cordova

Tags: android, cordova

Can anyone please show me how to get an email registered to a phone into my cordova application? In my application, there is a registration page which users must register with their emails and instead of them typing it in, I want to use cordova to get the current email on the phone into the textfield of the registration page named `"email"` and also if possible get the firstname and lastname the user used in registring his email on his phone into a textfield

Comment: which version of cordova you are building with ?

Comment: i'm building with cordova 5.1.1

Comment: ok i have an idea i will develop this plugin and if you can wait till eod i can post the details for you to consume ?

Comment: ok, i will wait on that

Comment: ok i have created the plugin i should be able to let you know in some time.

Comment: ok, will be waiting on that.

Answer (score 0):

so you can use the following plugin

```
[User-Info-Plugin][1]
```

The way to add would be to use the following command

`cordova plugins add https://github.com/xarv/UserInfo-Cordova-Plugin.git`

after the adding check your config.xml for proper entries.

Usage:

```
var success = function(string){
    alert(string);
  };
  var error = function(string){
    alert("error");
  };
  getInfo("email",success,error,"email",[]);`
```

The getInfo method is the one you should use with action as "email". this should be done after cordova has been loaded i.e. inside onDeviceReady after deviceready has been fired.        `document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);`

Also in your manifest you would have to add

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

as a permission.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if any issues do revert back.